# Why there divided by 2 in cost function derivation process ？

Tags: machine-learning

In  [Linear Regression With One Variable | CostFunction — Andrew Ng](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yuH4iRcggMw&list=PLLssT5z_DsK-h9vYZkQkYNWcItqhlRJLN&index=5)  video 5:17,

the cost function derivation process, I understand this step:

[image]

but why there(5:17) comes :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're calculating cost function, you're trying to get `mean square deviation (MSD)`. If you don't divide by `m`, it's not really the mean square value, it's basically `sum of deviations`.

And the half, it's nothing but taking halves of MSD, can be called half-MSD. When you take the derivative of the cost function, that is used in updating the parameters during gradient descent, that 2 in the power get cancelled with the 1/2 multiplier, thus the derivation is cleaner. These techniques are or somewhat similar are widely used in math in order "To make the derivations mathematically more convenient".

Answer (score 0):

IIRC it's so when you take the derivative you don't need to scale it. It doesn't really make a difference as the loss will be *mathematically* equivalent, see: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/313172